# Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError?'

Tags: swift

The errors i'm getting :

1)Extra argument 'error' in call

2) Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError?' (aka 'inout Optional') to expected argument type '()'

My Code:

```
func initUdpSocket(){
        var error : NSError?
        mUdpSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        mUdpSocket.enableBroadcast(true,error: &error)
        mUdpSocket.beginReceiving(&error)

    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__),\(__LINE__),\(data)");
    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didSendDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__),\(__LINE__),\(tag)");
    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didConnectToAddress address: NSData!) {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__),\(__LINE__),\(address)");
    }
    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didNotConnect error: NSError!) {
        print("\(__FUNCTION__),\(__LINE__),\(error)");
    }

}
```

Can i know what is wrong with my codes??  I haven had any errors before updating my xcode.

Comment: Swift 2 – I guess you're talking about Swift 2 – introduces a new error handling syntax. It's described in the language guide

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.2 and Objective-C Interoperability in Error Handling**

This appears to be happening because, in Swift 2.2, Objective-C methods that take a `NSError **` for their last parameter are converted to the Swift `throws` method equivalent.

You can find more information on this topic on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6), using the 3rd and 4th sections, excerpted below.

**Error Handling ([excerpt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6))**

> In Cocoa, methods that produce errors take an `NSError` pointer parameter as their last parameter, which populates its argument with an `NSError` object if an error occurs. Swift automatically translates Objective-C methods that produce errors into methods that throw an error according to Swift’s native error handling functionality.

For example, consider the following Objective-C method from `NSFileManager`:

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
                  error:(NSError **)error;
```

In Swift, it’s imported like this:

```
func removeItemAtURL(URL: NSURL) throws
```

**Catching and Handling an Error ([excerpt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6))**

> In Objective-C, error handling is opt-in, meaning that errors produced by calling a method are ignored unless an error pointer is provided. In Swift, calling a method that throws requires explicit error handling.

Here’s an example of how to handle an error when calling a method in Objective-C:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *fromURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/old"];
NSURL *toURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/new"];
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [fileManager moveItemAtURL:URL toURL:toURL error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.domain);
}
```

And here’s the equivalent code in Swift:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let fromURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/old")
let toURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/new")
do {
    try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(fromURL, toURL: toURL)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```

Additionally, you can use catch clauses to match on particular error codes as a convenient way to differentiate possible failure conditions:

```
do {
    try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(fromURL, toURL: toURL)
} catch NSCocoaError.FileNoSuchFileError {
    print("Error: no such file exists")
} catch NSCocoaError.FileReadUnsupportedSchemeError {
    print("Error: unsupported scheme (should be 'file://')")
}
```

**Question-specific Code**

In this code example, this means that, in Swift 2.2, the `enableBroadcast(error:)` method of `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` would be `enableBroadcast() throws` and would need to use an explicit `do-catch`.

Similarly, the `beginReceiving()` method of `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` would turn into `beginReceiving() throws` and would also require the use of a `do-catch`.